# The scrolling down is very slow

Tags: python, web-scraping, scroll, selenium-chromedriver

So i am trying to extract reviews from google play. But the problem is the scrolling down of the reviews sections is very slow and if i manually scroll down, it is faster than the automatic scrolling. The page keeps on loading for long time to scroll. I have attached the code below.

```
scroll_action = ActionChains(driver).scroll_from_origin(scroll_origin, 0, 7000)
                scroll_action.duration=0.3
                scroll_action.perform()
                html= driver.page_source
                soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
                df=extraction()
```

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

You can try [move_to_element](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/actions_api/mouse/#move-to-element)

```
reviews = WebDriverWait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.RHo1pe")))
last_review_num = len(reviews)
...
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(review[-1]).perform()
```

If review doesn't appear until you hover over it, you can move to that review first.

Edit:
Test scrolling with this

```
url = "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ludo.king&hl=en"
driver.get(url)
all_reviews_btn = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '(//*[contains(text(), "See all reviews")])[1]')))
actions.move_to_element(all_reviews_btn).perform()
time.sleep(3600)
```

Comment: I have tried it but the result is the same. And also i am new to using the selenium so can you please explain a little bit more

Comment: I have added a piece of code, can you check it and see if there is a difference?

Comment: what should i define "actions"

Comment: `actions = ActionChains(driver)` from snippet above. You need to import `ActionChains` as `from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains`. Check the link to docs I mentioned and the link to example inside that link.

Comment: It says action chains doesnt have any attribute called move to element. I also tried action builder, the result remains the same.

Comment: are you sure you used `ActionChains().move_to_element(all_reviews_btn).perform()`?

Comment: It's the same one from your code that you said was working. If you are using VSCode editor, you can do `Ctrl+Click` on `ActionChains` to see available methods. If `move_to_element` method is not present, you might want to upgrade/reinstall selenium. You could try `driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element)` to scroll using javascript but you are more likely to run into another problem if you don't resolve this one.

Comment: I tried but sadly the browser scrolls down to the end of the page and doesnt move in to the see all reviews section. It stops once it reaches the end of the page.

Comment: Yes that's because you need to **click the button** to **open** the *all review section*. And once the *all review section* opens, you need to simulate what you do in normal browser i.e scroll that *infinite all review section* each time you want new data to add.

Comment: If you really want to learn selenium, you can just go through [Selenium documentation for python](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html) or [Selenium official documentation for all languages](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/). Skim through *entire* docs at least once.

Comment: Actually I did and figured it out...it works fine now. Thanks 